# Running a C file from within another C file in Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, file, posix

I need to run a C program from within another C program on Ubuntu. Something like
scanf i //say i=2 is entered

```
switch (i){
case 1: print xyz;
break;
case 2: cc abc.c -lpthread (and then) ./a.out //execute this command to execute file with name abc
break;
}
```

How to do that? I searched Google thoroughly but couldn't find suitable answers.

---

Edit: I am now running the said execute command from a bash file. It works and solves my requirement in an easy way :D

```
#! /bin/bash
read a
if [ $a -eq 1 ]
then
    cc ex.c -lpthread
    ./a.out
else 
    echo "hi"
fi
```

Comment: You say you want to `run` a c program, but the example you show is talking about`compiling` a c program. Which is it?

Comment: hi..sorry..i need to compile and then run also..edited..@OliverMatthews

Comment: You can also do a system call.  Lets you interact with the shell, so you could compile and run the program, or anything else you want to do on the shell.  It is synchronous, however, which means that your program will not continue execution until the shell commands complete.  If you want to continue while the sub-program runs, you will need fork as mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: A "*c file*" isn't run. It might be compiled and linked producing an executable, which in turn can be "*run*".

Comment: Note that you should probably only try running the program if the compilation succeeds.  You can add `&&` after the compilation command line; that will then only run `./a.out` if the compiler succeeds: `cc ex.c -lpthread && ./a.out` (can all be on one line given that it is so short).

Answer (score 4):

You need to make use of [fork() and exec()](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/icsrts/Tutorials/fork%5fexec/) to spawn off a subprocess (*regardless* of what that process is doing - I note you're compiling and running a new process).

If you want to spawn off a process and wait for it, simply relying on the return (error) code to determine success, then `system()` is an option.

Comment: @osgx - of course! Now edited to reflect that possibility too. Thx

Comment: System() does run a shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the *system* function to do the compilation and *fork* a new process and *exec* the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Might as well fill out the Big Three Options: [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) if you want to process some of the output from your spawned child in the parent C program.

If you are running something with as many potential outputs as a compiler `fork & exec` are probably inevitably where you will end up.